# cudaMallocManaged for host-initiated variable

Tags: c++, cuda

I have an Eigen array generated by the host device, which I would like to put onto the GPU via CUDA's Unified Memory. Most examples I found first pass a pointer to `cudaMallocManaged` and allocate the memory there before initiating the array afterwards. How do I do the opposite, ie allocate the memory on the host, fill it with values, and then move it to the Unified Memory system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done, unless you copy the data from your host allocation to the managed allocation.   (Which presumably is not what you are asking about.)

On an IBM Power9 platform, your [host allocated data can still be accessed from device code](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-system-allocator), however there is currently no corresponding method on x86 platforms.

Comment: Copying would mean having a duplicate array in memory, right? That could work I suppose. Would this look like `cudaMallocManaged(*new_variable, size); cudaMemcpy(*new_variable, *old_variable, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); free(*old_variable);`?

Comment: approximately. `cudaMallocManaged(&new_pointer, size); memcpy(new_pointer, old_pointer, size); free(old_pointer);`

Comment: There can't be support for this on x86 platforms, and never can be, because it's in the essence of the platform. On Power9, the Volta GPU is integrated so as to have direct acces to system memory without going through a PCIe bus - it's a "first-class citizen" just like the CPU, so that all system memory is unified.

Comment: I wouldn't say never.  The linux HMM patch if it ever gets here, will essentially enable this sort of behavior on x86.  Yes, there are implementation differences.  But the net effect is that data allocated using a system allocator will be directly accessible to the GPU, even over PCIE.  But the linux HMM patch is not ready yet.